# I dont understand this proof. How can we multiply Mtotal (mi) with a singular ai of some particle. Is ai a collection of all tangential accelerations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Fi acts on the entirety of the object, Mi is the collection of all particles in the object. So, it makes sense that ai is the collection of all tangential accelerations of the particles. I don't know if my assumption is correct because the book is too vuage. It might be because I'm missing something though. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: No. $m_i$ is mass of i-th element of a body, $a_i$ is acceleration of i-th element, so $r_i m_i a_i$ is torque acting on i-th element of body.

Answer (score 0):

The body has been divided up into many small parts, and a subscript $i$ is being used to label the parts. If there are $N$ parts having masses $m_i$, for $i$ in the range $1$ to $N$, then the total mass of the body is
$$
M = m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_N = \sum_{i=1}^N m_i
$$
The total force on the body is
$$
{\bf F} = {\bf F}_1 + {\bf F}_2 + \cdots + {\bf F}_N = \sum_{i=1}^N {\bf F}_i
$$
Each ${\bf F}_i$ produces a torque about the given axis. The presentation in the diagram and text becomes rather unclear at this point because there is no mention of a vector product or the role of the direction of the force in calculating the torque.

For a flexible body the different parts can have different angular velocities about any given axis but for a rigid body (which is what the text is talking about) the motion has to keep distances between parts of the body fixed, and this implies all the parts have the same angular velocity about some axis about which the body is rotating.

Comment: Thank you sir, 
I completely understand the angular velocity & angular acceleration part. However, at the start of the proof the text used tangential acceleration, which is the part I'm confused about. Is it talking about a collection of all the different tangential acceleration about each particle? Or am I missing something?

Many thanks good sir.